# Autosum entire column

Tags: google-sheets

On Google Sheets, I enter my sales for the month in Column F. How can I get column F to Auto Sum so that the total always appears below the bottom entry?

Comment: Do to mean that when you type in `F2` 100, `F3` says 100 or that for example `F10` says 100?

Comment: If I type in $100 in F2, $300 in F3, and $50 in F4, I would like F5 to have the total of all columns above ($450 in this example) and then if I type in $500 in F5, F6 would have the $950 total, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a very elegant solution, but at least it does not require a script.

1. Enter the formula `=IF(F2="","",IF(2*F2=SUM(F$2:F2),"",SUM(F$2:F2)))` in the cell F3.
2. Drag it down throughout the column.
3. Right now, the column is empty. But if you enter 100 in F2, the number 100 will appear in F3, as the total. If you type 300 in F3, the number 400 will appear in F4. And so forth.

The conditional statements in item 1 ensure that the cell shows the sum of the cells above it only if (a) its neighbor above it is not empty; and (b) the neighbor above is not itself the sum of the previous cells.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be inline? If you move it to an adjacent column, this is trivial to complete with the equation: `=SUM(F:F)`